# SQL-Stmt where dependencie matches TBL1 OR TBL2

Tags: sql, join

.
HI SQL-Gurus ;-)

I would like u to help me with a SQL-Statement:

What I want is simple:

Following Tables:

- Person (for firstname, lastname etc.)
- Associate (user_id)
- Appointment (appointments allways have 1 associate)
- Contact (every Contact has 1 associate)

I need a statement that only gives me Associates(persons) who either have one or more appointments OR/AND who have one or more Contacts.
So the other way round: I don't need to have Associates listed who don't appear in one of the two Tables.

So far it looks like this:

```
SELECT 

    firstname,
    lastname,
    IIf (PERSON.firstname = '', PERSON.lastname, PERSON.lastname +  ', ' + PERSON.firstname) AS fullname 

FROM 

    SOBA_LIVE.crm7.PERSON 
    INNER JOIN 
        SOBA_LIVE.crm7.ASSOCIATE ASSOCIATE ON PERSON.person_id=ASSOCIATE.person_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SOBA_LIVE.crm7.ASSOCIATE ON APPOINTMENT.associate_id=ASSOCIATE.associate_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SOBA_LIVE.crm7.ASSOCIATE ON CONTACT.associate_id=ASSOCIATE.associate_id 

WHERE

    ASSOCIATE.person_id <> 0
```

The last line "ASSOCIATE.person_ID <> 0" filters associates that are no human beings ;-)

I hope u understand what I mean and can help me. 
Thanks so far!

Regards
Many

Comment: how crystal reports is linked with this requirement?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I need the statement for CR but for this question it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this in your 'where' part:

```
where ASSOCIATE.person_id <> 0 and exists
(select a.person_id from appointments a where a.person_id=PERSON.person_id 
union
select b.person_id from contacts c where c.person_id=PERSON.person_id)
```

Comment: Close enough ;-) Thank you :-)